# Serving JSON data from a Firebase website

Tags: node.js, json, firebase

I am setting up two websites under the same Firebase project for the first time and need some guidance.

The first website is a React app and it already works.

For the second site I created a folder named SecondSite. I also created a subfolder called public under SecondSite. At this point public only contains a static HTML file (index.html) that I am able to serve on the second web site. I did that following a couple of documents and tutorial that I found.

Now this is what I want to do next with my second site, I want it to serve JSON contents that I plan to get from the contents of the realtime database in my Firebase project. What is the minimum I need to do for that?
I believe I need to do some more setting up inside the SecondSite folder (to be able to connect to the DB), like installing some node.js modules, but I am not sure how to go.